# What is the final equation used to produce new prediction using kknn on R

Tags: r, prediction, k-nearest-neighbour

I have trained my data using kknn on R and was able to predict on a new data set. However, I'd like to know what the actual final equation is so I can reproduce the prediction manually.

My training code is as follows:

```
train.kknn (mod1~S+T+H+W, train, kmax = 25, kernel = c("triangular"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The KNN modeling technique doesn't actually produce an equation like a linear regression model would.

When you train the knn model, it builds a structure (I think this uses a kd-tree) for future optimized searching.

It then runs each of your predictions through that structure to search for the (in your case) 25 nearest neighbors and blends their results (your "mod1" variable) using your triangular kernel.